# Removing SKSpriteNode when touched

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to delete SKSpriteNodes when they are tapped, however, I can't get the node that I want to be removed, just the latest one created. And because the nodes are spawned every second, when I tap on one it deletes the next one. Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var weapon = SKSpriteNode()
var badGuy = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    spawnBadGuy()
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock(spawnBadGuy)
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, wait])
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))


}
func spawnBadGuy(){
    badGuy.name = "badguy"
    badGuy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
    badGuy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    badGuy.setScale(0)
    let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(0.15, duration: 2)

    let moveToSide = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(min: 0 + 50, max: self.size.width - 50 ), y: CGFloat.random(min: 0 + 50, max: self.size.height - 50 )), duration: 2)
    badGuy.runAction(moveToSide)
    badGuy.runAction(scaleUp)


    self.addChild(badGuy)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if touchedNode.name == "badguy"{

            badGuy.removeFromParent()

        }
```

I have had the same problem in two completely different projects and haven't been able to figure out a solution. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are writing the same variable. try:

```
func spawnBadGuy(){

    let localBadGuy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBall")
    localBadGuy.name = "badguy"
    localBadGuy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    localBadGuy.setScale(0)
    let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(0.15, duration: 2)

    let moveToSide = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(min: 0 + 50, max: self.size.width - 50 ), y: CGFloat.random(min: 0 + 50, max: self.size.height - 50 )), duration: 2)
    localBadGuy.runAction(moveToSide)
    localBadGuy.runAction(scaleUp)
    self.addChild(localBadGuy)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if touchedNode.name == "badguy"{

            touchedNode.removeFromParent()
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if touchedNode.name == "badguy"{
            touchedNode.removeFromParent()
            break;
        }
    }
}
```